# Redis TLS configuration

Tags: ssl, redis

I have updated my Redis configuration file as below

```
#tls-port 6379
#port 0
tls-cert-file /tmp/redis.crt
tls-key-file /tmp/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /tmp/ca.crt
```

I am using OpenSSL Program to generate the above certificates.

This is how I startup my redis application

> redis-server /tmp/redis.conf

I have 2 questions, hopefully can get a response

Q1) I am using Redis version 7.0.10, when I put the tls-port and port in the redis.conf, my redis application won't be able to startup. Not sure what is the reason.

Q2) May I know how can I confirm that my redis is really configured with TLS/SSL?
I am not sure how to test if my redis is configured properly

Thank you.